# Remove given string from both start and end of a word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Data :

```
col 1
AL GHAITHA
AL ASEEL
EMARAT AL
LOREAL
ISLAND CORAL
```

My code :

```
def remove_words(df, col, letters):
    regular_expression = '^' + '|'.join(letters)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x:   re.sub(regular_expression, "", x))
```

Desired output :

```
col 1
GHAITHA
ASEEL
EMARAT
LOREAL
ISLAND CORAL
SUNRISE
```

Function call :

```
letters = ['AL','SUPERMARKET']
remove_words(df=df col='col 1',letters=remove_letters)
```

Basically, i wanted remove the letters provided either at the start or end. ( note : it should be seperate string)
Fog eg : "EMARAT AL" should become "EMARAT"
Note "LOREAL" should not become "LORE"

Code to build the df :

```
raw_data = {'col1': ['AL GHAITHA', 'AL ASEEL', 'EMARAT AL', 'LOREAL UAE',
                     'ISLAND CORAL','SUNRISE SUPERMARKET']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

Comment: Tried adding a word boundary?

Comment: Note your sample df text and the code to repro are not the same. Try `df['col 1'] = df['col 1'].str.replace(r'^{0}\b\s*|\s*\b{0}$'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, letters))), '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, let me try it and comment. But kindly note that the dataset is huge one more than 2 million. so is this the fastest method ?

Comment: It is a regex method. How fast it is depends on the data, how long the input strings are.

Comment: `.replace(r'(?s)^{0}\b\s*|(.*)\s*\b{0}$'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, letters))), r'\1')` might turn out faster especially when you have long strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern = r'^{0}\b|\b{0}$'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, letters)))
df['col 1'] = df['col 1'].str.replace(pattern, r'\1').str.strip()
```

The `(?s)^{0}\b|(.*)\b{0}$'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, letters))` pattern will create a pattern like `(?s)^word\b|(.*)\bword$` and it will match `word` as a whole word at the start and end of the string.

When checking the word  at the end of the string, the whole text before it will be captured into Group 1, hence the replacement pattern contains the `\1` placeholder to restore that text in the resulting string.

If your `letters` list contains items only composed with word chars you may omit `map` with `re.escape`, replace `map(re.escape, letters)` with `letters`.

The `.str.strip()` will remove any resulting leading/trailing whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bSvjZc/2).